# WebDriver to disable SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER in Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

`WebDriver` opens browser window, but I get `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`.
I tried to add this site as an exception in browser, but when new browser window opened I get the same message again instead of the website.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
options.setLogLevel(Level.ALL);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Are you using the latest jars of selenium, updated gecko driver and updated firefox browser

Comment: @ShubhamJain : Yes, I use the most recent version from each.

Comment: Please shareURL?

Comment: @iamsankalp89 : Same error : https://self-signed.badssl.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `setAcceptInsecureCerts` Capabilities as `true`

This simple code work for me :-

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Workspace\\StackOverlow\\src\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
 DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
 driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/");
```

OR

```
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Workspace\\StackOverlow\\src\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
     DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
     desiredCapabilities.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true);
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
     driver.get("https://self-signed.badssl.com/")
```

Change your gecko path in first line of code. Update gecko driver and firefox

[image]

Comment: added another .. try it out

Comment: I am using selenium 3.4.0 jars, geckodriver 0.18.0 and firefox 55.0.3 (64-bit)